Reference for computing cohomology of $Q_nS^0$ (the $n$-th component of infinite loop space)?
$Q_nS^0=\varinjlim_k(\Omega^kS^k)_n$, where $(\Omega^kS^k)_n$ refers to homotopy classes of maps $(S^k,\ast)\to (S^k,\ast)$ of degree $n$. I already know the case of $n=0$.
Is there any reference about calculation of its cohomology when $n>0$?

It's a loop space, so the path components are all homotopy equivalent to each other.

Oh, you are right. Thank you very much.
